# Google sign in API token expiration

Tags: android, google-signin

I'm using `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` for my Android app. In current version I plan only local authentication without backend server. I have implemented sign in according to [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java). It works, but over some random period of time user is automatically logged out. And user has to login again. I want to avoid automatic logout. I suspect that generated token has expired and should be refreshed but unfortunately I can not find any reference how to do that in Google docs for Android. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: have you find complete solution regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, cannot comment inline. But what do you mean by "user is automatically logged out"?

There's hidden token management internally, but token will be auto refreshed when it expires.

Assuming you've gone through the sign-in flow already. Then code should behave like below after you re-open your app:

```
OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // This code path should be reached if your last (refreshed) sign-in happens
        // within a short period of time
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                // This code path should be reached if your last (refreshed)
                // sign-in is a while back and token needs to be refreshed. But you
                // should still be able to get a successful googleSignInResult back.
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
```

Could you paste your code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the same `SilentSignIn` as Isabella mentioned, with some changes though. I could not get Google's suggested way of implementing the `SilentSignIn` to work, (which is exatcly the code Isabella posted). Instead I moved the `opr.setResultCallback` to above its enclosing if statement and then deleted the if statement itself.

You can see my more complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43059487/4561506