# Google Drive API logging out

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I'm using Google Login and successfully downloading files from drive to Android devices.  But it seems that after about 3 months the device logs out and needs to be manually logged back in.  Is there a way to prevent this or to log back in without manual intervention (i.e. programmatically). I don't want the device to ever logout.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this documentation in Google Account Help about [Stay signed in or out of your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/54490?hl=en). This is an initial solution that you can try.

> If Google keeps signing you out, here are some steps you can try:
>
> - Make sure **cookies are turned on**. Some antivirus or related software may delete your cookies.
> - If your cookies are turned on, **clear your browser's cache**. Note: While deleting your cookies may resolve the problem, it will also
>     remove your saved settings for sites you've visited.
> - Make sure you’re using the latest version of your browser.
> - Use a browser like Chrome to r**emember passwords** for you.
> - If you use 2-Step Verification, **add trusted computers and devices**.

If it is for Google sign in token expiration, you can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654482/silent-google-sign-in-in-android-background-service/43059487#43059487) about [`SilentSignIn`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi#public-methods) method that helps you to detect user revocation of access to your application on other platforms.